# TableRow weights scaling opposite of what I expect when using GraphView in my Android java app

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout, android-tablelayout

I've created the following layout xml-file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="some.package.MainActivity" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/mainRow"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/footerRow"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/footerLayout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

... and populate it with graphs from the GraphView api as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    int[] assetLayouts = new int[]{
            R.id.mainLayout,
            R.id.footerLayout,
    };
    int count = 0;
    for (int assetLayout :assetLayouts ) {
        GraphViewSeries exampleSeries = new GraphViewSeries(new GraphViewData[] {
                    new GraphViewData(1, 2.0d)
                    , new GraphViewData(2, 1.5d)
                    , new GraphViewData(3, 2.5d)
                    , new GraphViewData(4, 1.0d)
        });

        GraphView graphView = new LineGraphView(this, "" + ++count);
        graphView.addSeries(exampleSeries);

        FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(assetLayout);
        layout.addView(graphView);
    }
}
```

This behaves as expected and divides the screen in two parts, with one graph taking up the first top half, and the second one taking up the other bottom half. Now, I want to give the top graph/row more weight, i.e., it should be proportionally larger than the lower graph/row. So, what i did was set the top row (`mainRow`) to `android:layout_weight="2"`. I expect that the top row now should be twice as large as the bottom row, however, the opposite happens. The top one only get 33%, while the bottom one gets 66% of the screen real estate. This is opposite of the documentation I found:

> For example, if there are three text fields and two of them declare a
>   weight of 1, while the other is given no weight, the third text field
>   without weight will not grow and will only occupy the area required by
>   its content. The other two will expand equally to fill the space
>   remaining after all three fields are measured. **If the third field is
>   then given a weight of 2 (instead of 0), then it is now declared more
>   important than both the others, so it gets half the total remaining
>   space, while the first two share the rest equally.**

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html

What is going on here?

Sure I can work around it and just give the opposite weights of what I thought was right, but I'd rather do it right.

Answer (score 1):

Also when setting weight, set width (if orientation is horizontal) or height (if vertical) to 0dp. That way the width/height is calculated properly.